# display rows from two GridViews in single GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two GridViews on my .aspx page and both have different selectMethod, different data but having same HeaderTemplate. I want my .aspx will have only one gridView but different datasources. Is There any Possible way to accomplish this task.

Comment: You can merge your lists and bind the final list to your final datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello If You Have Multiple Data source You may use condition that which data source list you want to bind to your gridview

In this case you can use dynamic list to bind your data source dynamically at run time  as your header field is same  if your data field name is same then dynamic list will be perfect for you.

I am not sure that if you used `BoundField`  or `templatefield` or directly binding the datasource
As you didnt post your code i am posting a sample code for you hope you can find out something through this

```
//Suppose YOur Lists are List1 and List2 then 

 If(Condition1==true)
 {
 List1   // Your datasource list
 List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
 foreach(var data in List1)
 {
 data.Add(new {  
 Name =data.Name, 
 Address = data.Address
 });
  }

 GridView1.DataSource = data 
 GridView1.DataBind();
 }

 ///For Condition 2

 If(Condition2==true)
 {
 List2   // Your second datasource list
 List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
 foreach(var data in List2){
 data.Add(new { 
 Name =data.Name, 
 Address = data.Address
});
}
GridView1.DataSource = data 
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate variable to hold your merged data, then fetch your retrieved data into it (from both select methods you have), then assign this variable value to showing grid `*.DataSource` and then call the `*.DataBind();` method.

P.S. Make sure when merging the two source to have the same schema, otherwise you will have to loop on every set of results to extract it and merge it manually with the other set to have your new standard schema which should be rendered in `GridView` then.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Do you have any code for idea regarding this or any link.

Comment: You can share your block of code, we will work directly on it.
or here is an example:
assuming your both functions are returning lists ...

`
var result = new List<object>();
foreach(var item in YourFirstFunction())
     result.add(item);
foreach(var item in YourSecondFunction())
     result.add(item);

yourGridView.DataSource = result;
yourGridView.DataBind();
`

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

String query= "select *from Employee1 ; select *from Employee2";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);

SqlDataReader dr;

con.Open();

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = dr;

GridView1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).